# Adding params to Apache Spark's abstract Evaluator class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, evaluator

I'm building a Spark Application and am using the [`Evaluator`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/Evaluator.scala) class within some custom Estimators/Transformers.  I've run into an issue where the `Evaluator` base class does not implement the `metricName` param that most (all?) of its descendants (`RegressionEvaluator`, `BinaryClassificationEvaluator`, etc.) implement.  Specifically, when writing a Validator that takes an Estimator and an Evaluator as parameters (to `.fit` and then `.evaluate` a trained model), I would like to be able to store or log both the resulting `metricName` and `metricValue` produced by the `Evaluator`.  That would be pretty straightforward if I explicitly typed the `evaluator` param as either a `RegressionEvaluator` or `BinaryClassificationEvaluator`, but if I type it simply as the base `Evaluator`, then I get `val getMetricName is not a member of ...` error at compile.  I can potentially extend the `Evaluator` class and use that (as below), but that creates some type mismatch headaches in other areas (`found Evaluator, required MyEvaluator`) that are not worth the benefit of just making the `metricName` available.

```
trait HasMetricName extends Params {
  val metricName: Param[String]

  def getMetricName: String = $(metricName)
}

abstract class MyEvaluator extends Evaluator with HasMetricName
```

So, my question: Is there a simple way that I can mixin or tell the compiler that my `Evaluator` class has a `metricName` value or else insert the `MyEvaluator` class in a way that won't propogate type mismatch errors in other areas?  The ideal solution would be to simply edit the `Evaluator` class to include this param, but that is buried in a top level Apache project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a perfect case for a structural type:

```
def myMethod(e: Evaluator { def getMetricName: String }): ...
```

Comment: Yup, that makes perfect sense!  Thanks!